# Java - Get text from webpage

Tags: java, web-applications, web-scraping

I am beginning a new project, its something I have never attempted with in Java, and I have been researching before hand. My research has not got me much further than where I started.

Basically my project will do this:

- Search a website and get
  corresponding data (Basically search
  its search engine based of the query
  that a user inputs, then returns the
  corresponding results)
- The user clicks on one of the results
  and then program will show certain
  values (the values will be on the
  result's webpage)

So far all I kind of know on how to do this is Web Scraping. I couldn't find any examples so I am still kind of in the dark about this.

Is this really possible? I will be using Java with the Android SDK. I kind of have a idea, but my Java knowledge does not contain anything to do with Web Pages, etc.

Thanks in advanced,
Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutch is a great tool, but may be a bit overkill for a small project. if you are looking for something really quick and dirty and easy to understand you should look into [crawler](http://java.net/projects/crawler)

see an example of use here:
http://java.net/projects/crawler/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/examples/com/torunski/crawler/examples/ExampleDownloadWithHTMLParser.java?rev=429

You can probably drop this into your project and be scraping in 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Probably the best library for this is [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/). Its based on powerful library stacks like Lucene and  is very matured. Look in to their tutorials and you might find all the necessary information for a quick poc.